# How do i fix the CKEditor error in a custom file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ckeditor5

i am trying to use custom ckeditor in my react project. I used ckeditor 5 online builder and got a custom folder like this:

config.ts

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2014-2023, CKSource Holding sp. z o.o. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */

import { ClassicEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic';

import { Autoformat } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat';
import { Bold, Italic } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles';
import { BlockQuote } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote';
import { CKBox } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckbox';
import { CloudServices } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services';
import type { EditorConfig } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core';
import { Essentials } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials';
import { Heading } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading';
import {
    Image,
    ImageCaption,
    ImageStyle,
    ImageToolbar,
    ImageUpload,
    PictureEditing
} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image';
import { Indent } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent';
import { Link } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link';
import { List } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list';
import { MediaEmbed } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed';
import { Paragraph } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph';
import { PasteFromOffice } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office';
import { SourceEditing } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-source-editing';
import { Table, TableToolbar } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table';
import { TextTransformation } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing';
import { Undo } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo';

// You can read more about extending the build with additional plugins in the "Installing plugins" guide.
// See https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/plugins/installing-plugins.html for details.

class CustomEditor extends ClassicEditor {
    public static override builtinPlugins = [
        Autoformat,
        BlockQuote,
        Bold,
        CKBox,
        CloudServices,
        Essentials,
        Heading,
        Image,
        ImageCaption,
        ImageStyle,
        ImageToolbar,
        ImageUpload,
        Indent,
        Italic,
        Link,
        List,
        MediaEmbed,
        Paragraph,
        PasteFromOffice,
        PictureEditing,
        SourceEditing,
        Table,
        TableToolbar,
        TextTransformation,
        Undo
    ];

    public static override defaultConfig: EditorConfig = {
        toolbar: {
            items: [
                'heading',
                '|',
                'bold',
                'italic',
                'link',
                'bulletedList',
                'numberedList',
                '|',
                'outdent',
                'indent',
                '|',
                'imageUpload',
                'blockQuote',
                'insertTable',
                'mediaEmbed',
                'undo',
                'redo',
                'sourceEditing'
            ]
        },
        language: 'en',
        image: {
            toolbar: [
                'imageTextAlternative',
                'toggleImageCaption',
                'imageStyle:inline',
                'imageStyle:block',
                'imageStyle:side'
            ]
        },
        table: {
            contentToolbar: [
                'tableColumn',
                'tableRow',
                'mergeTableCells'
            ]
        }
    };
}

export default CustomEditor;
```

and I use it in TDEditorNew:

```
import React from "react";
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";

// import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
// import DecoupledEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document";
import CustomEditor from "./config";

import axios from "axios";
import * as authHelper from "@/app/modules/auth/core/AuthHelpers";

import {
  requestGET,
  requestPOST_NEW,
  requestPUT_NEW,
  API_URL,
  FILE_URL,
} from "@/utils/baseAPI";
const uploadAdapter = (loader) => {
  const { token } = authHelper.getAuth();

  return {
    upload: () => {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const file = await loader.file;
          const response = await axios.request({
            method: "POST",
            url: `${API_URL}/api/v1/attachments/public`,
            data: {
              files: file,
            },
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          });
          resolve({
            default: `${FILE_URL}${response.data.data[0].url}`,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
    },
    abort: () => {},
  };
};
function uploadPlugin(editor) {
  editor.plugins.get("FileRepository").createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
    return uploadAdapter(loader);
  };
}
const TDEditorNew = ({ data, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <CKEditor
      editor={CustomEditor}
      config={{
        extraPlugins: [uploadPlugin],
      }}
      data={data}
      onChange={(event, editor) => {
        const data = editor.getData();
        onChange(data);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default TDEditorNew;
```

```
import TDEditorNew from '@/app/components/TDEditorNew';
...
<div className='col-xl-12 col-lg-12'>q
                  <FormItem label='content' name='content'>
                    <TDEditorNew
                      data={form.getFieldValue('content')}
                      onChange={(newContent) => {
                        form.setFieldsValue({ content: newContent });
                      }}
                    />
                  </FormItem>
                </div>
```

The result returned is an error:

```
@ckeditor_ckeditor5-react.js?v=be2d4ad6:1084 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')
    at _IconView._updateXMLContent (chunk-PUXRYV7X.js?v=be2d4ad6:2330:27)
    at _IconView.render (chunk-PUXRYV7X.js?v=be2d4ad6:2313:10)
    at _IconView.<anonymous> (chunk-AKXJUVNH.js?v=be2d4ad6:7658:37)
    at _IconView.fire (chunk-AKXJUVNH.js?v=be2d4ad6:7337:35)
    at <computed> [as render] (chunk-AKXJUVNH.js?v=be2d4ad6:7661:21)
    at ViewCollection._renderViewIntoCollectionParent (chunk-PUXRYV7X.js?v=be2d4ad6:1125:12)
    at ViewCollection.<anonymous> (chunk-PUXRYV7X.js?v=be2d4ad6:1019:12)
    at ViewCollection.fire (chunk-AKXJUVNH.js?v=be2d4ad6:7337:35)
    at ViewCollection.addMany (chunk-AKXJUVNH.js?v=be2d4ad6:9371:12)
    at ViewCollection.add (chunk-AKXJUVNH.js?v=be2d4ad6:9347:17) {phase: 'initialization', willEditorRestart: false}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcqky.png)

Previously I used ClassicEditor from @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic and it worked normally, however I needed to display SourceEditing so I customized a new file as above.

So where am I going wrong and what do I need to fix?